# Positioning a DIV tag in top of the page

Tags: css, web

I need to Positioning a DIV tag in top of the page like in the **StackEchange** top menu bar

i used to following code but there is the space

```
div.topbar{
    width:100%;
    background:#C0C0C0;
    border:1px;
    border-color:gray;
    border-style:solid;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial;
    top:auto;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Put Div Tag at top of page without space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333190/css-put-div-tag-at-top-of-page-without-space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need to add:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
```

Answer (score 2):

`position: absolute` is not needed if is the first child of the containing element. Just do a

```
margin: 0
padding: 0
```

and you'll have the added benefit of the next element in the flow positioned correctly after and not under the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
div.topbar{
  position:absolute;
  top:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `position:absolute;` and `top:0;`?

You may need to `clear:both;` the next element, though.