# CSS Put Div Tag at top of page without space

Tags: css

I want to put a div tag with id "wrapper" at top of page, but the problem is
that there is a white space between the div tag "wrapper is yellow color"
and the top of page.

My question is how can I remove the white space between the div tag and the top 
of page?

Here is my code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <style type='text/css'>
     body {
     margin: 0;
     padding:0;
     }  
     
     #wrapper {
     width:1000px;
     text-align:center;
     margin-right:auto;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-top:0px;
     background-color: yellow;
     padding:0px;
     }
     </style>
     </head>

     <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
       Testing
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: At me there isn't any space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this in the css code:

```
{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
}
```

You can use the `right` or `left` to make a space between the div and the corner

Comment: PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE FORMAT YOUR POSTS!

Comment: Sorry , i'm new here so i don't know how to do this

Comment: Thanks for you question.Yes, it moved to the top and left of the corner.
But I want it to be at the top and center of the screen.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. But when put position:absolute , overlap between to div. and if I change position:relative , the white space appear between my first div and the top of page . how can I make the first div at the top of page and prevent overlap between two div ?

Comment: for my case,I change the code to  position:relative;
 top:-25px; and this run correctly with me. thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5910170/2670516

Try replace all your code by:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding:0;
    }    
    #wrapper {
      width:1000px;
      text-align:center;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-top:0px;
      background-color: yellow;
      padding:0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  Testing
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this ..

```
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}
```

hope this works